# Meaning of "White noise uncorrelated in time"?

Tags: correlation

On page $3$ of these [slides](http://www.chem.wisc.edu/%7Ecui/chem860_dir/ppt_09/Chem860_09_L23_LD.pdf), it says:

> It’s often a good approximation to make the random force “white” and
> “uncorrelated in time”.

And this equation just pops out of nowhere.
[image]

I know white noise, but I have no idea what this equation means. Where does this definition come from? And what does it mean?

Comment: In its current form, I fear this question will become useless if the link to those slides ever dies. Questions here should be as self-contained as possible. Please [edit] your question to include more information (for example, what the quantities in the question represent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This equation is the autocorrelation, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation) .
(or [autocovariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocovariance) , depending of usages :-) . Quite the same by a $\sigma$ ).

Not correlated in time is like each sample being independently distributed in time. So the correlation between $x_{t0}$ and $x_{t1}$ is 1 if $t0=t1$ otherwise 0.

Comment: Can you teach me why after the autocorrelation, these two normal distribution will generate a delta function?

Comment: Thank you so much ! I have been struggling with this question for hours. This helps a lot !

Comment: Have you read the wikipedia link ? autocorrelation/autocovariance is basically $s(t') = \int x(t)x(t+t')dt$ (for $x$ centered and scaled). s(0) is obviously not 0, while for $t'\neq 0$ decorrelated/independent makes the integral cancel since E(xy)=E(x)E(y) .